# Have file always listed first in Google Drive directory

Tags: google-drive

When viewing Google Drive in `Grid View`, is there a way to have a specific file always listed first within a directory?

One obvious solution is to add something like "000" to the beginning of the file (e.g. `000 My Desired First File`) so that it gets sorted to the top, but I'm looking for a non-hacky way to "pin" a file at the top of the list.

```
Example:

 - My Desired First File
 - Apple File
 - Banana File
 - Cat File
 - Dog File
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. The only way is to give it a lead by renaming it. There isn't such an option to pin stuff. Best you can do is **Star** them, but that wouldn't "give it a lead":

[image: 0]